# Load .phtml template from Observer Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.2, magento2.1

I'm trying to load my .phtml files in the template folder within my observer but I'm getting this error

> Invalid template file: 'VENDOR_MYModule::Category/index.phtml' in module: 'VENDOR_MYModule' block's name: 'category_0'

Here's the structure of my files

```
app
 + code
    + VENDOR
      + MYModule
        + Block
            - Category.php
        + Controller
            + Category
               - Index.php
        + etc
            + frontend
                - routes.xml
        + Observer
            - CategoryObserver.php
        + view
            + frontend
                + layout
                    - header_category_index.xml
                + templates
                    + category
                        - index.phtml
```

Now the content of my `Block/Category.php` is below

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MYModule\Block;

class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

}
```

The content of my `Controller/Category/Index.php` is below

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MYModule\Controller\Category;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;     
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {       
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }   
}
```

The content of the `layout/header_category_index.xml` is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category" name="category_items" template="VENDOR_MYModule::category/index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

The content of my `.phtml` is just a simple `<h1>Hello world</h1>`. Now in my `Observer` I'm trying to load this `.phtml` file but I can't load it and getting the error. The content of my Observer `Observer\CategoryObserver` is below

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{           
    $layout = $this->_layout->create();
    $block = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category')->setTemplate('VENDOR_MYModule::Category/index.phtml')->toHtml();        

    $this->_logger->debug("[DEBUG]::" , [$block]);
}
```

Here's the content of my `events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
        <observer name="category-edit" instance="VENDOR\MYModule\Observer\CategoryObserver" />
    </event>   
</config>
```

But I'm getting the error as mentioned above. Any idea on how to load this .phtml file to the observer? I'm planning to write the content of this .phtml file to a .txt file. But I can't proceed since I tried outputting it but I'm still getting an error

> UPDATE:

Tried my code using the Frontend controller/action access and the block successfully loaded. Now I think there's another way or implementation when retrieving the .phtml in the Admin part or in the Observer. Also note that the observer is triggered when I try to edit/save a catalog->category.

Comment: I am not sure what requirement you want to fulfill with this, it seems like a wrong approach. I would suggest trying some other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

could you please check that you are calling following class as $layout in your observer:

> \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory

In addition, you need to set response header and body instead of returning html.

```
protected $_layoutFactory;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory) {
    $this->_layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{           
    $layout = $this->_layoutFactory->create();
    $block = $layout->createBlock('VENDOR\MYModule\Block\Category')->setTemplate('VENDOR_MYModule::Category/index.phtml')->toHtml();

    $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
    $response->setHeader('Content-Type','text/html')->setBody($block->toHtml());
    return;
}
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: thanks for the effort. But still getting the same error. Also note that this layout is being access from the admin part. So basically upon saving of new categories then this observer is triggered